# I am not able to use result.ops method to view All the documents inserted using insertMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to insert new documents in my task collection and the print all the documents inserted by using result.ops method

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'task-manager'

MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
if (error) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to database!')
}

const db = client.db(databaseName)

db.collection('tasks').insertMany([
    {
        description: 'Clean the house',
        completed: true
    },{
        description: 'Renew inspection',
        completed: false
    },{
        description: 'Pot plants',
        completed: false
    }
], (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Unable to insert tasks!')
    }
    console.log(result.ops)  //returns undefined
    console.log(result)   // returns only 2 methods 
})
})
```

// console.log returns only 2 methods insertedcounts & insertedids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68424173/16483030
Here is your answer.  In version 4 insertOne returns insertOneResult that have only 2 properties: acknowledged and insertedId.
So you can use insertedId. That makes sense because if it is one, an array is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was my code first

```
postsCollection.insertOne(this.data).then((info) => {
  resolve(info.ops[0]._id)
})
```

But the `ops[]` method is no longer supported ... so the solution is to change it to `insertedId` and it works

```
postsCollection.insertOne(this.data).then((info) => {
  resolve(info.insertedId)
})
```