# NodeJS + MongoDB: insertOne() - get the inserted document from result.ops

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

In the docs I see we can use the returned insertOneWriteOpResultObject.ops to retrieve the document inserted. ([Docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#%7EinsertOneWriteOpResult)), but when doing so I get back `undefined`.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
const collection = db.collection("testcollection");
collection.insertOne({"name": "Test_Name", "description": "Test desc."},
(err, result) => {

    console.log("After Insert:\n");
    console.log(result.ops); //undefined but should return the document
    
    collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
        
        console.log("Found:\n");
        console.log(docs);

        db.dropCollection("testcollection", (err, result) => {

            client.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check version of MongoDB Node.js Driver with command `npm list mongodb`. If it is version 4 then you can not access `result.ops`. In version 4 [insertOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/collection.html#insertone) returns [insertOneResult](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/insertoneresult.html) that have only 2 properties: acknowledged and insertedId.

Comment: do you know what is the correct way in version 4 to get inserted document after insert? Query for it?

Comment: Looks like there is no another choice than only query for it

Comment: it's crazy! Why would they remove `ops` and be silent about it?

Comment: `result.insertedId`, doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

There have been some changes in 4.x.
You can refer to the link below.
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/HEAD/etc/notes/CHANGES_4.0.0.md

[image: See this snip]

Comment: Please explain the main idea in your answer. The link should support the answer, not replace it (links can be changed over time).