# What is this error?: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication

While trying to build user authentification using mongodb and express I came across an error. The error basically happens every time I click submit on the website. That's the first problem, the second is after I click submit the page just keeps loading and never changes as if its stuck or trapped in an infinite loop. I tried deleting everything in the database and starting over but that didn't work. A little advice would be appreciated.

The error:

```
app: authRouter {
  app: authRouter   acknowledged: true,
  app: authRouter   insertedId: new ObjectId("613b5afd2139aeac87bd9682")
  app: authRouter } +0ms
  app: authRouter TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  app: authRouter     at addUser (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\src\routers\authRouter.js:24:30)
  app: authRouter     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) +19ms
```

authRouter.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const debug = require('debug')('app: authRouter');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.route('/signUp').post((req, res) => {
  const {username, password} = req.body;
  const url = 
  'mongodb+srv://Yoshi:Yumcmaster1@cluster0.atic5.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
  const dbName = 'testdb';

  (async function addUser(){
      let client
      try {
        
        let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
          
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        const user = {username, password};
        const results = await db.collection('users').insertOne(user);
        debug(results);

        req.login(results.ops[0], ()=> {
          res.redirect('/auth/profile');
        });
        



      } catch (error) {
        debug(error)
      }
      client.close();
  }());

});
authRouter.route('/profile').get((req, res) => {
    res.json(req.user);
})

module.exports = authRouter;
```

Comment: the error is probably on this line `results.ops[0]`

Comment: I believe so to but what do I do ? @depperm

Comment: it depends on what you're trying to do exactly. Add a check for `results.op[0]` or omit entirely?

Comment: That's up to you. The error is telling tou that `results.ops` is undefined.

Comment: @depperm I just checked the database and it turns out all the logs have made it so I believe it works but I still get that error and the page just keeps loading without going anywhere. I'm not sure what you mean by omit but I don't believe i'm check for anything.. I'm following a tutorial btw

Comment: what tutorial? I'd double check exactly what has been done and that where you are (if following along) is at a working code spot. Most tutorials are thorough

Answer (score 0):

I certainly don't know what your trying to do because I'm not so good at mongodb  but I found a rather intresting thing in passport js docs and stackoverflow

`Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which req.login() can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user.`

`Check version of MongoDB Node.js Driver with command npm list mongodb. If it is version 4 then you can not access result.ops. In version 4 insertOne returns insertOneResult that have only 2 properties: acknowledged and insertedId.`

[NodeJS + MongoDB: insertOne() - get the inserted document from result.ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412072/nodejs-mongodb-insertone-get-the-inserted-document-from-result-ops)

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and run into this same issue. It's certainly a MongoDB version issue. I got past along this issue by sending the 'results' to the login page:

```
req.login(results, ()=>{
     res.redirect('/auth/profile');
});
```

On the profile page you just get this:

```
acknowledged    true
insertedId  "652557c55339292182e6b264"
```

This actualy says that an insert was made with the insertedId

Hope this helps